# DPDT button latching switch

Tags: switches

i am having a cool idea when i turn on my pc i want my monitor to come out of th desk using a linear actuator.
The problem comes with the switch, for the linear actuator i need a DPDT switch, but the switch once pressed should not turn off until the pc and the actuator are done, i ended up with the dptd button latching switches, but i cant find any on internet, like the switch when pressed should turn on the pc and moving the actuator forward, when pressed again should shut down the pc and moving the actuator in reverse, but in my case the switch while turning on, the pc will stay on and hard resetting all the time while the actuator goes up, and if i take the momentary switches it will turn on the pc but the actuator will come up just gradually that means every time i press the switch, i would really like to use one switch to do this 2 opposite things, is it possible? what should i do.
Thnk you guys

Comment: As much as volunteers on this forum would like to help you, they will find it hard to imagine all the details. Can you please show a schematic of this arrangement? It will result in a more coherent and focused response.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the PC power switch actuate the monitor drive, do it this way. Have the monitor drive circuit actuate the PC power. When the monitor is partly or fully raised, it actuates the PC power. The OFF sequence you can figure out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you would want the actuator powered the entire time the computer is on, you would want it to stop once the monitor is in place.

You would need a circuit to detect a button press and power the actuator until the monitor reaches it's deployed position, and then turn the actuator off.
On a second press it would power the actuator in reverse until the monitor is back in it's storage position and them shut the actuator off again.

There are a number of ways this could be done, you could possibly do it with relays and microswitches, but a microcontroller and position sensors would probably be the best way.